# upstart script with ngrok, process seems to run but doesnt do what is supposed

Tags: upstart, ngrok

I used a really simple upstart script to run an ngrok tunnel at startup.

> description "my service description"
>
> start on runlevel [2345]
>
> stop on runlevel [016]
>
> respawn
>
> exec /home/ubuntu/ngrok http 8081

I am able to start it, and i can see the process runing:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/etc/init$ ps -ef | grep ngrok
root     27768     1  2 01:56 ?        00:00:04 /home/ubuntu/ngrok http 8081
ubuntu   27809  2688  0 01:59 pts/0    00:00:00 grep --color=auto ngrok
```

I am able to stop the process to.

But the ngrok command is not creating the tunnels that it should.
If i run it on the command line with the correspondent syntax there is no problem.

Am i using the *exec stanza* incorrectly?
Any ideas?

Thank you

**UPDATE:**

I have been able to solve the problem using the following solution (context, i am using a free account of ngrok)

Upstart init file:

> description     "Ngrok upstart init file"
>
> author          "lps"
>
> start on runlevel [2345]
>
> stop on runlevel [!2345]
>
> respawn
>
> script
>
> sleep 20
>   exec /usr/bin/ngrok http 8081 -log=/home/ubuntu/ngrok.log
>   -log-level=debug -authtoken=**************************
>
> end script

But i still cant understand why the following, upstart init file is not able to do the same:

> description     "Ngrok upstart init file"
>
> author          "lps"
>
> start on runlevel [2345]
>
> stop on runlevel [!2345]
>
> respawn
>
> script
>
> sleep 20
>
> exec /usr/bin/ngrok http 8081
>
> end script

In the second file case my configuration file, ngrok.yml, is in the /home/ubuntu/.ngrok2/ folder. I will leave the ngrok.yml file in case someone wants to give it a go (i changed all the files and directories in this path to chmod 777, just to be sure it wasnt a permission problem).

ngrok.yml

> authtoken: **************************
>
> log: /home/ubuntu/ngrok.log
>
> log-level: debug

Comment: Maybe it's not finding the config file? Perhaps try using the `-config=/path/to/ngrok.yml` argument in the ngrok command.

Comment: @Pterosaur thank you. You are correct, for some reason ngrok is not using the default defined path to the ngrok.yml you have to show it...

Comment: It's probably because the YAML file is in your home folder, but you're not running ngrok as your user.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you for the alert. when running it as an upstart service what is the user under which the service is being executed? root user?

Comment: Yes, I believe it's running as root. Now I just have to fix the problem that my system won't boot at all since I installed upstart.